# URL to specific Instance of WebRole in Windows Azure

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, cloud, azure-web-roles

i have a WebRole in my Windows Azure Deployment with a few instances. In this Roles i do a lot of caching. So my client asks everytime another instance for a specific information, which is maybe not stored on the requested instance. All my cached informations got a "instance"-property, so i can route my request in the cloud to the specific instance (via internal endpoints).

Is there a way to get a URL for my instance and not my deployment? 
Something like:

instance1.mydeployment.cloudapp.net?

I think something would be really helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is. I'm not sure what SDK it came in, but in your csdef file you can alter your normal endpoints section to look like this

```
 <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="Endpoint1" protocol="http" port="80" localPort="80" />
      <InstanceInputEndpoint name="Endpoint2" localPort="80" protocol="tcp"><!--localPort must be 80 for this to work-->
        <AllocatePublicPortFrom>
          <FixedPortRange min="10016" max="10020"/> <!--make a range that covers the # instances you might need or scale too - bear in mind azure port limits ~25 -->
        </AllocatePublicPortFrom>
      </InstanceInputEndpoint>
    </Endpoints>
```

Now you should be able to access both

http://myapp.cloudapp.net:10016

http://myapp.cloudapp.net:10017

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is very similar to the `sticky session` issue with Tomcat servers. Since you live in a .NET world I highly suggest that you change your architecture to not relay on this sticky routing.

If you really want to achieve that specific goal (which I don't imagine why one would want), it is possible through Application Request Routing. It is not easy, but it is feasible. you can read [here about how to install ARR on Azure Web Role](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2011/07/21/how-to-install-iis-application-request-routing-in-windows-azure/). But you have to maintain automatic configuration and reconfiguration of ARR, especially when you add or remove instances.

Frankly, the whole idea of sticky sessions is broken. Even if you manage to handle automatic installation and configuration of ARR, tell me what will happen when the Azure Fabric controller takes 1 instance down for Guest OS Update. What will happen to your users that were served by that instance?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use distributed Windows Azure Caching as a ready robust solution for sharing cached data between instances.

As far as I know, you can not get separate URLs for individual instances.

EDIT: the following answers might help:
[Azure Web Role Internal Endpoint - Not Load Balanced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12341513/azure-web-role-internal-endpoint-not-load-balanced)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2011/10/21/Running-Memcached-on-Windows-Azure-for-PHP.aspx

I know, it is a tutorial for PHP and memcache but it uses InternalEndpoint for Role Communication via TCP. Maybe it helps you to understand, how to fix your problem.